# Disable dependent picklist in visualforce page

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, visualforce, picklist

I tried successfully to disable every input and select in my page:

```
$('input').prop('disabled',true);
$('select').prop('disabled',true);
```

But in my page I have two picklist, the second one is dependent from the first in SFDC.
And when I disable every select, the dependent is not disabled.

I try to hide it, but it doesn't work either!
It only works from the Console, but I need to put these controls in a Js function.

Comment: Might help depending on Jquery version you are using try $('select').attr('disabled',true);

Answer (score 1):

I've found that dependent picklists are not rendered on the page in time for code in a ready function to affect them.  The only way I've been able to make changes to the dependent list is to do it in a setTimeout method that fires in 1000 milliseconds or so.  It's not ideal, but it does seem to work.

Comment: this is absolutely correct. we have tried and its working fine. Thanks!!